# My page takes long time to load so am not able to identify an element from the page.Please provide me a solution

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, java, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.id("oPortalUser_LoginID")).sendKeys("xxxxx");

driver.findElement(By.id("oPortalUser_Password")).sendKeys("xx");

driver.findElement(By.id("xxx")).click();
```

After clicking on Login button, it takes lot of time to load. So am not able to identify an element from the next line.

```
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='LftNav']/ul/li[7]/a")).click();
```

I have tried implicit and explicit waits. But its not working every time.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3
You can use javascript to check if the document has loaded or not, and can perform your actions accordingly.

Comment: This in combination with WebDriverWait should be a good fix. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9904784/467546

Answer (score 0):

if u tried with Implicit and Explicit wait last try with below code you might get success.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='text3']")));
```

Comment: I have tried sleeping methods but when the load is more, it takes more time and the script fails. So I need an alternative solution without using implicit and explicit waits. @sameer joshi

Comment: increase more in miliseconds of thread.sleep method

Comment: i have tried it but it does not work correctly in the time where load in the website is high.@sameer joshi

Comment: check my comment

Comment: I have tried both of this. It is working but it not working everytime.

Comment: if u use Testng framework then add priority to ur methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29891/discussion-between-sameer-joshi-and-kripindas).

Comment: Whatever you've described, it seems that the loading time of the webpage is very high (that may be due to many reasons). So the remedy is to either increase the wait time to such an extent that the page successfully loads or optimize the page for less loads, then test it. I would suggest you do a load test first to check the performance bottlenecks first